# Postfix Evaluation in C

Tags: c, stack

I'm trying to write a program to evaluate postfix expressions in C, This is the program I wrote, But I seem to get a stack underflow error.

```
int evaluate(char a[]){
int i = 0, opr1, opr2, res;
int eval;

struct stack infix_stack;
init(&infix_stack); //Initialize stack top to -1.

for(i = 0; (eval=a[i])!='\0'; i++){
    if(isdigit(eval)){
        push((eval-'0'), &infix_stack);
        showStack(&infix_stack);
    }

    else{   
        opr2 = pop(&infix_stack);
        opr1 = pop(&infix_stack);

        switch (a)
        {
        case '+':return(b+c);break;
        case '-':return(b-c);break;
        case '*':return(b*c);break;
        case '/':return(b/c);break;
        default:
           printf("Unknown operator\n");
           return 0;
           break;
        }
    }


}
return(res = pop(&infix_stack));

}
```

I am getting a stack underflow error.

Comment: While we're at it, those 4 `case` statements probably shouldn't actually have `return` statements in them.

Comment: Notation: x+y, you try to pop two numbers but only one of them is in the stack at them moment, Prefix notation: + x y, no numbers are yet in the stack, Postfix notation x y +, both numbers should be available. So it entirely depends on your input string how the stack is utilized, but yo should use postfix notation with the code you have right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i try to run your program with `2 + 3`, I'm gonna get underflow.

The 2 is going to get pushed onto your stack:

```
if(isdigit(eval)){
    push((eval-'0'), &infix_stack);
    showStack(&infix_stack);
}
```

But then, the plus is going to cause this to happen:

```
opr2 = pop(&infix_stack);
opr1 = pop(&infix_stack);
```

I just double popped, and got underflow as a result. Are you giving the program valid postfix input?

Comment: Yes i tried it with these, and i got these stack snapshots with input 12+3*

1


2
1


3
3

Stack Underflow

Comment: I guess a better question is, can you provide a valid postfix string that breaks it?

Comment: Okay, got the error, I was trying 1 2+ 3* , but my program translates the 1 2 into 12, and as a result I'm getting the underflow. Fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell when you get an expresion like "1+2"
you push "1" on to your stack but when you encounter the "+" you execute your "else" logic which pops "opr2" and "opr1"  from your stack -- but you have only pushed the value "1" on to the stack. The value "2" has not yet been encountered.

Comment: Yes, but "1+2" isn't a postfix expression.